# Continue A Laravel Job Upon Exception

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

I have a Laravel Job that is being dispatched. The job gets some records to process then calls an API with each. The API could occasionally could throw an error e.g. HTTP500 etc. This library (Goose) uses Guzzle.

I want to catch the error, flag the record to try again later and continue with the rest of the records in the loop.

My code is as follows **but when an error occurs, the foreach loop ceases and the job does not continue.**

My guess is that the Job Handler in Laravel is throwing a fatal error and the job is being halted at a higher level.

```
public function extractArticles() {

    $articles = $this->fetchArticlesToExtract();

    $goose = new GooseClient();

    foreach($articles as $article) {

        try {

            //Get the Article Data - Errors can happen here

            $articleData = $goose->extractContent($article->source_url);

            //Do Some Processing

            $article->save();

        }  

    catch (\Goose\Exception $e) {

        //Set a flag to come back later

        //Try continue with next record
        continue;
    }

}       
    return;
}
```

How can I tell the Job to continue? There is only a small set of errors that can occur here and I have written the logic to 'try again', so I'm happy to not stop the job completely.

Comment: Check your `}` you have too many and in the wrong places

Comment: Your curly braces are incorrectly placed for this to work.  If I were you, however, I would create a seperate job which contains the logic for one particular article.  Then have this job just dispatch the others jobs onto the queue.  This has the benefit that you can just have your queue deal with the Guzzle exceptions, and you will be able to increase performance if you have multiple queue workers that are active.  I think this will increase your comfort a lot.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, David. That is an interesting idea!

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `}` and they are in the wrong places

```
public function extractArticles() {

    $articles = $this->fetchArticlesToExtract();

    $goose = new GooseClient();

    foreach($articles as $article) {

        try {

            //Get the Article Data - Errors can happen here

            $articleData = $goose->extractContent($article->source_url);

            //Do Some Processing

            $article->save();

        }  

    //} removed

        catch (\Goose\Exception $e) {
            //Set a flag to come back later

            //Try continue with next record
            continue;
        }
    } 
    return;
}
```